wavelink не хочет подключатся к локальному lavalink серверу
вот конфиг лавалинк сервера:
server:
  port: 2333
  address: "0.0.0.0"
  http2:
    enabled: false
lavalink:
  server:
    password: "youshallnotpass"
    sources:
      youtube: false
      bandcamp: true
      soundcloud: true
      twitch: true
      vimeo: true
      nico: true
      http: true
      local: true
    filters:
      volume: true
      equalizer: false
      karaoke: true
      timescale: false
      tremolo: true
      vibrato: false
      distortion: false
      rotation: false
      channelMix: false
      lowPass: false
    bufferDurationMs: 400 
    frameBufferDurationMs: 5000 
    opusEncodingQuality: 10
    resamplingQuality: LOW 
    trackStuckThresholdMs: 10000
    useSeekGhosting: true : 6 
    playerUpdateInterval: 5
    youtubeSearchEnabled: true
    soundcloudSearchEnabled: true
    gc-warnings: true

metrics:
  prometheus:
    enabled: false
    endpoint: /metrics

sentry:
  dsn: ""
  environment: ""

logging:
  file:
    path: ./data/logs/

  level:
    root: INFO
    lavalink: INFO

  request:
    enabled: true
    includeClientInfo: true
    includeHeaders: false
    includeQueryString: true
    includePayload: true
    maxPayloadLength: 300


  logback:
    rollingpolicy:
      max-file-size: 512MB
      max-history: 30

вот кусок кода где я создаю ноду:
import wavelink

async def connect_nodes(self) -> None:
    await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
    await wavelink.NodePool.create_node(
        bot=self.bot, 
        host='http://0.0.0.0', 
        port=2333, 
        password='youshallnotpass'
    )
    wavelink.Player.autoplay = True

и вот что мне это чудо выдает:
Connection Failure: Cannot connect to host http:80 ssl:default [getaddrinfo failed]
брандмауэр выключен
вейвлинк форк https://github.com/davidcanas/Disnake-Wavelink
с сторонними бесплатными серверами работает.

локальный адрес - 127.0.0.1

user7860670, все равно такая же история.

я выяснил что lavalink запускается только на порту 8080, а wavelink потыается подключится только по порту 80. значения которые я установил ничего не значат. не знаю как исправить
